# What is the correct way to restrict access to properties that need to be assigned from another assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

For example, I have the following code defined in assembly A:

```
public abstract class Message
{
    public int ID { get; internal set; }
    public Message Parent { get; internal set; }
}
```

From assembly B, I need to do the following:

```
instanceOfMessage.ID = MethodToGetUniqueIDNumber();
instanceOfMessage.Parent = MethodToGetParent(); // Returns null /w no parent
```

Currently, I'm using the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) compiler option to get around this:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo ("AssemblyB")]

// Namespace stuff here

public class Message
{
    public int ID { get; internal set; }
}
```

It kind of feels yicky having to mess with a compiler option to make this work. So, my questions are:

- Is it okay to use InternalsVisibleTo in this situation?
- Should I just make the property(s) public and hope no one changes anything?
- Should I even be doing this at all?

<strike>My end goal is that someone, likely just my team and I, should be able to use a Message, but enforce that properties like ID never get changed from outside the classes that manage them. However, we still need to be the ones to create the instances of the messages and such.</strike>

My end goal is that my team and I should be able to inherit from Message in a third assembly, Assembly C. Assembly C only knows about Assembly A. Assembly B gets dynamically loaded later on. C will use interfaces provided by A to send messages to B.

Comment: You already considered `internal` and `public`. There's also the possibility `protected` which would mean that the property could be set only in classes deriving from `Message` (even classes in other assemblies).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My end goal is that someone, likely just my team and I, should be able to use a Message, but enforce that properties like ID never get changed from outside the classes that manage them. However, we still need to be the ones to create the instances of the messages and such.

One common approach in this type of situation would be to actually use an interface for the message, and then implement the interface within AssemblyB.

This allows your messages to be created, but not modified later, as you can still have full control over the implementation.

```
public interface IMessage
{
    int ID { get; }
    IMessage Parent { get;  }
}
```

Then your other assembly can just implement this with a private class, and return the appropriate message, without fear of it being able to be modified.

Comment: This answers the question asked, however I made a mistake in my end goal and forgot to define what I meant by the word "use". That should read "inherit from". Please see the edits above.

Comment: @MGSoto Do they need to subclass it, or just provide the message "details"?  If so, that can be a member of the Method type instead of an actual "Message' subclass...?

Comment: Yes, Message must be subclassed, as the details of a message will change by adding additional properties.

Comment: @MGSoto In your situation, having an `IMessage<T>` with a message details as the `T` may be more appropriate.  You could create a message with ANY content in that case...

Comment: Perfect, that should handle my situation appropriately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `private set` and define the `ID` and `Parent` when you call the constructor?

```
public class Message
{
    public Message(int id, Message parent) // Message constructor taking in ID and parent from external
    {
        ID = id;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public Message Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

This call below from outside your `Message` class.

```
Message instanceOfMessage = new Message(MethodToGetUniqueIDNumber(), MethodToGetParent());
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for answering. I made a couple of edits to clarify the question as I missed an important piece. Those properties need to be set after the instance of the class is already created.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go one step further and create a static factory method:

```
public class Message
{
    public static Message CreateInstance(int id, Message parent)
    {
        // Add code here to check security of caller

        return new Message(id, parent);
    }

    private Message(int id, Message parent)  
    {
        ID = id;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public Message Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

To create an instance of the message you would now call:

```
Message instanceOfMessage = Message.CreateInstance(MethodToGetUniqueIDNumber(), MethodToGetParent());
```

Now I can complelty control the creation of an instance of the object, and once created it can not be modified.